# My first PostgreSQL schema - How to handle multiple payments

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have been designing my very first db schema but I am a little stuck. I will offer the ability to "extend" the items posting with an additional payment after the initial payment, but my schema does not allow more than one payment ID to be linked to a single item.

I was wondering if anyone could give me any advice on how I could rearrange this schema to handle multiple payments on a single item. Id rather not have to encase the whole lot in something like this if possible:

```
ID
Item
Payment
```

This is what I have currently:

```
-- Company Table
CREATE TABLE company (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);

-- Country Table
CREATE TABLE country (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    iso VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Location Table
CREATE TABLE location (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(100),
    country_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES country (id),
    coordinate VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Source Table
CREATE TABLE source (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Item Table
CREATE TABLE item (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    solrid VARCHAR(25),
    title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    truncated_description VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    keyword_description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    page_url VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    create_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    company_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES company (id),
    source_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES source (id),
    location_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES location (id)
);
```

Comment: You're describing a classic one-to-many relationship between item and payments. Is there a reason you're not creating a payment table and foreign keying each row to the corresponding item table?

Comment: You should also make `country.iso` unique.

Comment: What do you mean by making country.iso unique please?

Comment: @Jimmy: `iso VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE,`. Every table here should *probably* have a column or set of columns that's declared unique, in addition to the primary key.

Comment: Thank you. Do I still need serial primary key?

Comment: "item", "source", and "location" are overly generic names. Also, what if an item belongs to an individual, and not a company? Why store the co-ordinates as varchar? You won't be able to find by proximity if you do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If payments are only ever for a single item then you *should* do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE payment (
  id SERIAL,
  itemid INTEGER REFERENCES item(id),
  amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
)
```

There are other possibilities, such as arrays, but they aren't worth it given your requirements.  Don't fight the database.

Comment: I wouldn't use the `money` datatype. It doesn't work very well with different locales. Using `decimal` is better.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but I get an error as shown in the gist description. Is this what you meant? https://gist.github.com/4706151

Comment: Sorry hand-typed and there was an error in there.  Try it now.